# Python threading lock not waiting for a user input

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I`m running a lot of threads.

And in some piece of code, I'm using threading lock with `input()` function.

```py
lock = threading.Lock()

# ...

def function_runned_in_threads()
    with lock:
        is_valid = False
        response_result = input('Is response valid? y/n (n)')

        if response_result == 'y':  # Brakepoint here resolve problem
            is_valid = True

        some_function(inst, is_valid)
        print("Output spike!")

# ...
```

Here the example of output without breakpoint

[image]

And with breakpoint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to `acquire()` and `release()` your lock, this way:

```py
def function_runned_in_threads()
    with lock.acquire():
        is_valid = False
        response_result = input('Is response valid? y/n (n)')

        if response_result == 'y':  # Brakepoint here resolve problem
            is_valid = True

        some_function(inst, is_valid)
        print("Output spike!")

        lock.release()
```